# Python asyncio streams: No stop byte

Tags: python, python-asyncio

While I was writing a program that sends and receive some JSON from a service, I stumbled upon a challenge. The server doesn't send a stop-byte (not going to lie, took me a few hours to realize it), it's just byte-by-byte JSON. Not even single quotes.

I was looking for an elegant solution before giving up and doing a while loop that keeps adding byte by byte in a buffer and checking if it's a valid JSON.

Has anyone ever had to deal with something similar?

Comment: one normalty needs to add some code, so that answers can build upon it.

But in advance: if you are reading data from a socket you can ask for a larger amount of bytes: if the total available data is less than that, the read won't block - and you can check if you have valid JSON after reading this larger block. Then, just  repeat the read if there are open JSON brackets.

Comment: @jsbueno I tried something like this, but the read method from StreamReader only returns the received data when the declared amount (n) is reached. And unfortunately, those JSON messages don't actually have a fixed size. Also, apparently the "stop byte" should be named EOF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by reading byte by byte and adding it to a buffer. Every time I read a byte, I check if the buffer is a valid JSON.

```py
def is_json(string: str) -> bool:
    try:
        json.loads(string)
    except ValueError as e:
        return False
    return True


class MyClient:
# ... my implementation of asyncio's client streams using OOP...

    async def receive(self) -> str:
    # Method used to read data from the server
        msg = ''
        while self.connected:
            data = await self.reader.read(1)
            log.debug(f"Read: {data}")
            msg = msg + data.decode()
            if is_json(msg):
                log.info(f"Received: {msg}")
                return msg
        log.warning(f"Client disconnected!")
```

Hope this helps someone.

Also, if you have a better/more elegant alternative, please, share.